# Excel lookup issue

Tags: excel

Hi hopefully someone can help me. Its been a while since I have used excel and am really struggling to do something which seems rather simple.

I have 2 separate worksheets with a lot of data. As an example worksheet 1 has 800,000 rows. With each row having a unique code. Worksheet 2 has 20,000 rows and also has the same unique codes that are found in worksheet 1. But the codes in worksheet 2 have specific data that is in a separate column that are related to each one of the 20,000. What I am trying to figure out is how I can get worksheet 1 to lookup the unique codes in worksheet 2 and the additional data in the next column  then when it finds the corresponding codes that match from the 800,000 it adds the extra data that I have in the separate column relating to the related data in worksheet 1.

quick example.

worksheet 1 has 800,000 different items of clothing. Each piece has a unique number.
Worksheet 2 has 20,000 items of clothing from worksheet 1 but also has an extra column for item colour.

I would like worksheet 1 to lookup the unique codes in worksheet 2 find the codes in sheet 1 from the 800,00 and then add the item colour to each unique code in worksheet 1.

Sorry if that's a bit cryptic.

Best Regards

Jez

Comment: Try reading up on the `=vlookup(...)` formula.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I undertood the question, but the example shows how lookup works

[image]

this is the formula logic used:

```
 =IFNA(VLOOKUP($A3,$E$3:$F$4,2,FALSE),"-")
```

`2` is the column index to grab the value (code). you can use match(..) to find the column name if you don't want a constant number.

The `$` sign is to lock the row/columns, when you extend the range to apply to other cells.

```
IFNA (... ,"-") allows you to add something if id tableA is not in present in tableB.
```

From lookup help:

[image]